# TextInputLayout doesen't show hint for first EditText in below 5" screens

Tags: android, xml, android-xml

I am facing issue in devices which are smaller than 5" size. It doesen't show hint only for first edit text. but it works fine for larger device where screen size is more than 5.2". Can you please help in my below code?

Thanks in advance.

[Device screen is 4.8" and it doesen't show title for first field. i.e. Name field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ERQy.jpg)

My xml code is as below :

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Name"
        android:textColorHint="@color/textColorWhite"
        android:theme="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_user"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/headerBackground"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:textColor="@color/textColorWhite"
            android:text=""
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

--> Put the hint in the TextInputEditText.
Follow the below code for reference

```
  <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/login_email"
        android:layout_width="395dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/email"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: android:theme="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat" Remove this line You will get the solution